# WPF App - How to obtain a reference to the corresponding System.Windows.Forms.Form?

Tags: wpf, forms, winforms-interop

In my WPF Project I have a WPF Window. I want to use [Sticky Windows Solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/stickywindows.aspx) in my WPF Project. The library wants only one parameter: the System.Windows.Forms.Form object.

Does it exist any way to obtain a Form object starting from a WPF Window object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. A WPF `Window` has no inheritance relation with a Windows Forms `Form`. However it would probably be possible to adapt the code from the library to mentioned so that it works with WPF...

Comment: I converted all reference to Form in my interface IFormAdapter. Now I have two implementation: WinFormAdapter and WpfFormAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

The approach others have mentioned of refactoring Sticky Windows Solution to support WPF forms sounds like your best option. If you really want to treat a WPF form as a Windows Form, maybe the below will help:

Would this work?

- Host your WPF form in an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)
  control. (ElementHost enables a WPF element to be treated as a Windows Form control.)
- Create a simple Windows Form
  containing only this ElementHost
  control.
- Use a reference to this Windows Form in
  your Sticky Windows Solution.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible, the article and code does present enough information for you to create a WPF version.